# FirebaseError: permission-denied Firebase Functions / How to allow unauthenticated function calls in emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a firebase function from my app.
I am using firestore and functions emulator with `firebase emulators:start`

Here is my cloud function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
 export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   response.send({"text":"Hello from Firebase!"});
 });
```

And this is how I call the function from my expo go app.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import {getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator, httpsCallable} from "firebase/functions";
import {useState} from "react";
initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBbBFNGMI",
  authDomain: "sixxxxxxxxxcc8.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sxxxxxxxxxxx8",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxcc8.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "6xxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "1:65xxxxxxxx13:web:d0exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7c"
});
const db = getFirestore();
const functions = getFunctions();
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080 )
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5000 )

const addMessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'helloWorld');
export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState("")
  addMessage({ text: "text" })
      .then((result) => {
        // Read result of the Cloud Function.
        /** @type {any} */
        const data = result.data;
        const sanitizedMessage = data.text;
        setResult(sanitizedMessage)
      }).catch(console.log);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{result}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I always get "FirebaseError: permission-denied"

I believe this is because I am not authenticated. My question
How do I disable the authentication for the emulator?

Comment: You are using `httpsCallable` with a function that is defined using `https.onRequest`. Make sure to use the same API on both the client and server side - either `httpsCallable` with `https.onCall` or `fetch` with `https.onRequest`. In either case, your API call should be in a `useEffect` to prevent additional problems.

Comment: Have you checked above suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a result of your rules. You will need to update your `firestore.rules`, search for the file and update it with this;

```
rules_version = 2

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: true;
    }
  }
}
```